# Input as defined variable shows as empty

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've this code:

```
@echo off
set/p user = Enter your username:  
echo Hello %user%
pause >nul
```

But when I enter any value and press enter, the cmd.exe output doesn't show me the value.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: That's because you've set a variable named `%user %`. You need therefore to use `Echo Hello %user %` or better still use the correct syntax for defining your variable, `Set /P "user=Enter your username: "`. **As the issue is a failure to use the correct syntax, your question should be deleted, _as it is of no use to future readers here_**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a space between your variable and the equal sign.

It must be:

```
set/p user= Enter your username:
```

Note that `user=` does not have a space.